# Resolve Jslint warning

Tags: javascript, jslint

```
var obj = {};
obj['a'] = value1;
obj['b'] = value2;
obj['c'] = value3;
```

What is wrong in above code, I am getting JS lint warning.
"['a'] is better written in dot notation"

Comment: Use `var objPlotBand = {};
obj.a = value1;
obj.b = value2;
obj.c = value3;`

Comment: OR you can also use `var objPlotBand = {
    a: value1,
    b: value2,
    c: value3
};
`

Comment: Also see https://jslinterrors.com/a-is-better-written-in-dot-notation

Answer (score 2):

It's recommending dot notation (See below) because it's unnecessary to look up an object property using a string. The following is easier to write and easier to read:

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = value1;
obj.b = value2;
obj.c = value3;
```

If you're creating an object, I'd actually recommend in-line object creation rather than piecing it together:

```
var obj = {
  a: value1,
  b: value2,
  c: value3
};
```

For future reference, the notation you used (bracket notation) is good for pulling up dynamic keys, like so:

```
var fruitCounts = {
  apples: 5,
  bananas: 3
};

var favoriteFruit = 'apples';

// How many of my favorite fruit do I have?
var favoriteFruitCount = fruitCounts[favoriteFruit];
```

Comment: It's called "bracket notation", not "selectors".

Comment: Good looking out, friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.a = value1
```

is better than

```
obj['a'] = value1
```